# check if input box start with http:// or www jquery

Tags: jquery, input

How to check is input text field start with http:// or www. on submit with jquery?

Answer (score 3):

No need for expensive regular expressions.

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
    return (this.length >= str.length)
        && (this.substr(0, str.length) == str);
}

String.prototype.startsWith_nc = function(str) {
    return this.toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase());
}

var text = $('#textboxID').val();
if (text.startsWith_nc("http://") || text.startsWith_nc("www")) {
    alert("looks like a URL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using regular expressions. The following goes through all textbox and prints to console if they begin with either http:// or www or not

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val().match(/(^http:\/\/)|(^www)/) != null);
})
```

See [fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZQRg2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQRg2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tomalak, there's no need for expensive regex here.

```
if($("#textboxID").val().indexOf("http://") == 0)
    alert('contains http://');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match("^"+str)==str)}

if($("#textboxID").val().startsWith("http://"))
    alert('contains http://');
```

Comment: Special characters for regular expressions should probably be escaped in `startsWith`. Either that or the function could be name something like `matchesPrefix` to give a clue that the parameter is actually a regular expression where `^` is prepended.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
if($("#my-input").val().match(/^(?:http:\/\/|www)/)) {
  // starts with http:// or www
}
```